# Using MongooseJS to Changing Mongodb _id to BSON UUID for ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ref

I currently use MongooseJS to change "_id" for each of my collections to a BSON UUID. On top of this I use a virtual to "id" to convert "_id" to its string equivalent. It works pretty good and gives me the benefit of using a UUID for the "_id" and not store it as a string which wastes disk resources.

Here is a snippet of code to show how this is done

```
const uuid = require("uuid-mongodb");
require("mongoose-uuid2")(mongoose);

let schema_options = {
    "id": false,
    "toObject": {
      "getters": true,
      "virtuals": true
    },
    "toJSON": {
      "getters": true,
      "virtuals": true,
      "transform"(doc, ret) {
        delete ret._id;
      }
    }   };

let schema = new Schema(
    {
      "_id": {
        "type": UUID,
        "default": uuid.v4,
        "required": true
      },
      "code": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "name": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true
      }
    },
    schema_options);

schema.virtual("id").get(function() {
   return uuid.from(this._id).toString();   
});

schema.virtual("id").set(function(uuid_string) {
  this._id = uuid.from(uuid_string);   
});
```

However, if I add a "ref" to another collection as with

```
schema.add({
    "test_references": {
      "type": [
        {
          "type": mongoose.Types.UUID,
          "ref": "test_references"
        }
      ],
      "required": true
    }
  });
```

I get a hash representation of the BSON UUID. Is there a way to make MongooseJS during a get operation to show these refs as UUID string representations

i.e. - I expect this "104e0f2e-3b54-405b-ba81-e87c5eb9f263" but get this "EE4PLjtUQFu6geh8XrnyYw=="

**Note:**: If this is the incorrect forum for this post, please let me know and I will move this to the correct forum immediately

Comment: I'm curious why you're using UUID for _id instead of ObjectId?

Comment: It is a requirement for our id's to use UUID's as record identifiers since other systems and languages do not have native semantics for ObjectId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I was able to apply a transform to the returned value.

This looks like the following:

```
this.schema.options.toJSON.transform = function(doc, ret, option) {
      let items = [];

      delete ret._id;
      ret.items.forEach((item) => {
        items.push(mongoose.uuid.from(item).toString());
      });
      ret.items = items;
      return ret;
    };
```

It is not ideal to look through all the items in the array but it is the best I could find in my research